# what happens if Sqlite database statements are not closed

Tags: java, sqlite

I am curious to know that, if  I create SQL statement for SQLITE database file in java as

```
public Statement GetStatement()
{
  if(connection==null || connection.isClosed())
  {
     connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:"+filePath);  
  }
  return connection.createStatement(); //Connection is private variable of type java.sql.connection
}
```

This statement returned by this function is used in executing insert, select, update SQL in different scenarios and multiple reads or multiple functions will be inserting, updating or selecting from database.
Now if I do not close the statements then are there chances of memory leaks.
But I close all the result set objects got by executing select SQL.
I know it is good practice to close the statements but what are counter effects if I do not do it?

Comment: Every SQLite statement has some heap allocated to it.  This is not garbage-collected heap.  It can "leak" if you do not close things.

Comment: @HotLicks but if I close the result set associated with statement does it makes difeerence

Comment: Probably not.  One could potentially use a statement several times.

Comment: @HotLicks I am creating statement object with every sql being fired is it a wrong behaviour?

Comment: It's certainly done.  It's a hair more efficient to reuse statements, but probably only worthwhile if you're in a loop or a small section of code where the statement will be reused repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite enforces sequential write-access to the database (one process at a time). This makes it vital that you close the database connection when you have completed any INSERT or UPDATE operations. If you don't, you might receive "DatabaseObjectNotClosed" exceptions when your script next attempts to write to it. Not to mention memory leaks, and possible performance  decrease.

Comment: SQLite enforces sequential write-access but it does not mean that I need to close database connection after every insert or update statement..........

Comment: You don't need to, but you should: the time to open/close connections is less of a hit that consuming memory by keeping connections open.

Comment: I am accessing database parallely and if after executing each sql if I close/open connection object performance decreases and then comes the problem of synchronization as one select statement is working on result set and other statement has finished work and tries to close the connection.... You can give it a try on large database where multiple threads are involved and see the difference....

Comment: Oh, desktop/server, not mobile - my fault :)

Comment: @Ezzored does the statement going out of scope count as closing? For example, a simple statement like: try { database.createStatement().executeUpdate("delete where rowid=2") } catch (SQLException e) { ... }